# Bootstrap 3 table-responsive not working within fieldset in mobile browser

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, mobile-browser

I am creating an web app and found that if I used fieldset and then table responsive then  a horizontal scroll comes on page on resolution of (320*480). If I removed fieldset then it worked fine .

I want  both of them in  my page.

I also tried by putting .table-responsive div in a row > col-xs-12 but it doesn't help same horizontal scroll comes.

```
<fieldset>
    <legend>Tester</legend>
    <div class="table-responsive">
      <table class="table">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>#</th>
            <th>Table heading</th>
            <th>Table heading</th>
            <th>Table heading</th>
            <th>Table heading</th>
            <th>Table heading</th>
            <th>Table heading</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>Table cell</td>
            <td>Table cell</td>
            <td>Table cell</td>
            <td>Table cell</td>
            <td>Table cell</td>
            <td>Table cell</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
</fieldset>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Github Issue](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/12359)

Fix it by adding `:display:table-cell; width: 100%` to fieldset

[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/56FtM/)

CSS

```
.responsive-fieldset {display:table-cell; width: 100%}
```

HTML

```
<fieldset class="responsive-fieldset">
```

Answer (score 0):

It turns out this issue can appear on mobile browsers when the viewport width is not set to the device's width. Add this element in your `<head>` and it will help Chrome at least.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
```

See the answer from @bootstrapthemer to get mobile Mozilla to handle fieldset width in the way we are used to. Mozilla is aware of this bug and [more info from Mozilla can be found here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/fieldset#Bugs).

Comment: hi @jeremy .Thanks  for the reply .But I updated the codebase and again tried in mozilla on same resolution problem still persist

Comment: Is this only in Mozilla? What is the device?

Comment: Resolution 320 * 480 in mozilla I am testing it. using the ctrl+shift+M  responsive test feature.

Comment: I've updated my answer to reflect this news, and that the missing `</tr>` tag was not the source of the problem.

Comment: OK, well my answer will help cover more browsers but @bootstrapthemer's answer is what you need for Mozilla.

Answer (score 0):

Just add this style in fieldset

```
min-inline-size: auto;
```

Comment: This may be a better answer, but you should explain why...