# Bootstrap responsive table not working within html table

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, html-table

As the title suggest a table within a table will not work with bootstraps responsive-table/table classes. Top table is the example.

This is the closest example to a solution involving a "fieldset" element.

Here's the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24939388/bootstrap-3-table-responsive-not-working-within-fieldset-in-mobile-browser)

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
 <tbody>
  <tr>
   <td>
              
              
    <div class="table-responsive">
                  
     <table class="table">
      <thead>
       <tr>
        <th>Table Header</th>
        <th>Table Header</th>
        <th>Table Header</th>
       </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
       <tr>
        <td>Table Data</td>
        <td>Table Data</td>
        <td>Table Data</td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
        <td>Table Data</td>
        <td>Table Data</td>
        <td>Table Data</td>
       </tr>
      </tbody>
     </table>
                  
    </div>
              
              
   </td> 
  </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="table-responsive">

  <table class="table">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Table Header</th>
        <th>Table Header</th>
        <th>Table Header</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>Table Data</td>
        <td>Table Data</td>
        <td>Table Data</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Table Data</td>
        <td>Table Data</td>
        <td>Table Data</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The outer table should also have class .table and .table-responsive so,

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table table-responsive">
 <tbody>
  <tr>
   <td>
              
              
    <div class="table-responsive">
                  
     <table class="table">
      <thead>
       <tr>
        <th>Table Header</th>
        <th>Table Header</th>
        <th>Table Header</th>
       </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
       <tr>
        <td>Table Data</td>
        <td>Table Data</td>
        <td>Table Data</td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
        <td>Table Data</td>
        <td>Table Data</td>
        <td>Table Data</td>
       </tr>
      </tbody>
     </table>
                  
    </div>
              
              
   </td> 
  </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply Cortez Nix, but after the update I still have a disabled overflow-x:scroll.